# php создать архив размером более 3Гб

Tags: php, zip

Есть сервер с доступом только php. цель слить весь сайт
ssh утерян, ftp Тоже. на сервере отключен exec из php поэтому использовать sh не получается.

```
disable_functions show_source,exec,passthru,shell_exec,system,proc_open,popen,eval,asser
```

создаю файл php:

```
<?php
$the_folder = '/home/alicedom/data/www/blabla.ru/1/';
$zip_file_name = 'archived_name.zip';
class FlxZipArchive extends ZipArchive {
    public function addDir($location, $name) {
        $this->addEmptyDir($name);
         $this->addDirDo($location, $name);
     } // EO addDir;
    private function addDirDo($location, $name) {
        $name .= '/';         $location .= '/';
      // Read all Files in Dir
        $dir = opendir ($location);
        while ($file = readdir($dir))    {
            if ($file == '.' || $file == '..') continue;
          // Rekursiv, If dir: FlxZipArchive::addDir(), else ::File();
            $do = (filetype( $location . $file) == 'dir') ? 'addDir' : 'addFile';
            $this->$do($location . $file, $name . $file);
        }
    } 
}

$za = new FlxZipArchive;
$res = $za->open($zip_file_name, ZipArchive::CREATE);
if($res === TRUE)    {
    $za->addDir($the_folder, basename($the_folder)); $za->close();
}
else  { echo 'Could not create a zip archive';}
?>
```

Пытаюсь выполнить, сервер долго думает, создает два файла по ~500Мб

```
 archived_name.zip.ve08AF
 archived_name.zip.WsVHcI
```

и страница крашится с ошибкой HTTP ERROR 500
что делаю не так?

Comment: Включайте вывод ошибок в php, читайте логи

Comment: если вы можете создать php файл значит есть доступ через ФТП или файл менеджер

Comment: Для начала выгрузите дерево директорий с размерами, а потом долго и нудно выкачивайте по частям. Можно сделать веб-морду, в которую будете забивать путь и скачивать его в архиве

Comment: Глупое предположение, но все же. У Вас в какой директории создает файлы archived_name.zip.* ?Я имею в виду не начинает ли Ваш zip добавляться сам с себя. P.S. Вариант №2, скрипт отваливаетса по таймауту выполнения.

Comment: @АнтонСкородумов нет, файл находится в хом директории сайта. а сливаю в архив папку которая глубже

Comment: @varz62 я создаю файл с помощью уже существущего CMS движка на сайте. просто тупо заливаю php файл(web shell) в одну из директорий.